# Tunnel between servers that supports any port

Tags: node.js, socket.io, tunnel

I'm trying to create a tunnel using Node.js that will allow me to access Server X from Server Y. Server X is connected to a router that isn't port forwarded and I won't know the IP of Server X until it connects, which means that Server X has to open a socket to Server Y and not the other way round.

I've successfully created a version of this using `socket.io`. Server X opens a socket to server Y, the user can then access Server Y in a web browser and Server Y proxies the requests down the socket to Server X.

What I would like to do is allow access to any kind of port on Server X, and forward not just web requests but requests of any kind. For example, I'd like to allow forwarding of SSH so I can access SSH on Server X through Server Y (doesn't have to be port 22). `localtunnel.me` is an existing service which is an exact example of what I want to achieve.

Are there any libraries that could help me achieve this, or can I build it from the ground up quite easily? I built the web request tunnel easily, perhaps it can be adapted to support not just web traffic? I've attached the code to my existing web tunnel below.

**Server X (connects to Server Y on port 3001, receives requests for data and sends it back:**

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3001');
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            console.log('Connected');

            // Register the event for request of data
            socket.on('request', function(data){
                // Get the path
                var options = {
                  host: 'localhost',
                  port: 3000,
                  path: data.path,
                  method: data.method
                };

                var request = http.get(options, function(resp){
                  resp.on('data', function(chunk){
                    socket.emit('response', { html: chunk });
                    // Probably need to fix this for file transfers. Use resp.on('end'
                  });
                }).on("error", function(e){
                  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
                });

                //Write our post data to the request
                request.write(data.data);
                //End the request.
                request.end();

            });
            socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
        });
```

**Server Y (listens on port 3001 to connect to Server X, and listens on port 3002 for requests from user in web browser to forward to Server X:**

```
app.listen(3001);

var rwPortalSocket;

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
    // Save the socket object
    rwPortalSocket = socket;
});

console.log('Data channel server running at http://127.0.0.1:3001/');

// Create web server
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // Send a request
    rwPortalSocket.emit('request', { path: req.url, method: req.method });

    // When we get a response
    rwPortalSocket.on('response', function (responseData) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(responseData.html);
    });

}).listen(3002, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Web server running at http://127.0.0.1:3002/');
```

## EDIT

I've now updated my code so that should support any TCP port or packet type. The code works fine when I tell `net.connect` to connect to a web server, but when I tell it to connect an SSH server, my SSH client complains with `Protocol error: expected packet type 31, got 20`

I've added an example of my new code connecting to an SSH server below.

**Server X (connects to Server Y on port 3001, receives requests for data and sends it back:**

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3001');
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            console.log('Connected');

            // Connect to 22
            var buff = "";
            var connected = false;
            var net = require('net');
            var client = net.connect({host: 'myserver.com', port: 22}, function() { //'connect' listener
                connected = true; 
                console.log('Connected to 22');
            });

            // Register the event for request of data
            socket.on('request', function(data){

                if (!connected)
                {
                    client = net.connect({host: 'myserver.com', port: 22}, function() { //'connect' listener
                        connected = true; 
                        console.log('Connected to 22');
                         client.write(data.data);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    client.write(data.data);
                }

                client.setMaxListeners(0); 
                // When data comes back to this service, we send it on to the other server
                client.on('data', function(data) {
                  //console.log(data.toString());
                    console.log('Server sent back: ' + data.toString());
                    if (connected)
                    {
                        socket.emit('response', { data: data });
                    } else {
                       buff += d.toString();
                    }
                });
                client.on('end', function() {
                  console.log('Disconnected from 22');
                    connected = false;
                });

                client.on('error', function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });

                console.log('Client sent: ' + data.data);
            });
            socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
        });
```

**Server Y (listens on port 3001 to connect to Server X, and listens on port 3002 for requests from user in SSH Client (terminal) to forward to Server X:**

```
app.listen(3001);

var rwPortalSocket;

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
    // Save the socket object
    rwPortalSocket = socket;
});

console.log('Data channel server running at http://127.0.0.1:3001/');

// Listen for tunnel requests
net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(s) { //'connection' listener
  s.on('end', function() {
      console.log('server disconnected');
  });

  s.on('data', function (d) {
    rwPortalSocket.emit('request', { data: d });
  });

    s.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });

    s.setMaxListeners(0); 

    // When we get a response
    rwPortalSocket.on('response', function (d) {
        s.write(d.data);
    });

});

server.listen(3002, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});

console.log('Web server running at http://127.0.0.1:3002/');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "connections" to Server X would all be TCP-based, you could have an SSH server running on both ends. Server X would then connect to Server Y to only forward some port on Server Y that would point to the SSH server running on Server X. Then you could use a node module like [ssh2](https://npmjs.org/package/ssh2) to connect to any port on Server X.

Another option for dynamic forwarding would be to set up a socks proxy as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/370931). From there you could use a socks client module from npm, such as [socks5-client](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-client).

If instead you have a fixed set of ports that you want have available, you could simplify the above solutions by just having an SSH server on Server Y and Server X connects and creates a port forward for each port you want to have available.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/mscdex/e6b24ba7886729495d1c) is an example of another option: connecting to Server X from Server Y via SSH and opening up connections on Server X using the SSH connection (via [ssh2](https://npmjs.org/package/ssh2)).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think what you suggested would be a good solution, creating a path to connect to the SSH server on Server X and then from there you can access any port. I couldn't allow SSH access on Server Y because Server X is insecure so I wouldn't be able to have Server Y SSH login credentials on there. I'm trying to create a tunnel to SSH, and I've updated my code to allow for TCP forwarding of any kind (or it should be). My SSH client keeps reporting 'Protocol error: expected packet type 31, got 20'. Any ideas? My updated code is above in the Edit section.

Comment: So Server X has an SSH server running that's accessible from Server Y?

Comment: Assuming Server X does have an SSH server running, [here](https://gist.github.com/mscdex/e6b24ba7886729495d1c)'s an example using the [ssh2](https://npmjs.org/package/ssh2) module for port forwarding.